# IOS 3DES in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I managed to import CommonCryptor.h via a bridge header,

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
```

However, while I'm trying to encrypt text use CCCrypt method(refer the way in Object-c), I got a compile error.

**'Int' is not convertible to CCOperation.**

```
var key:String = "wKNvJ4NuyW";

    func encrypt(text: String) ->String{


        var result:CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(
            kCCEncrypt, //Error here!!! it says 'Int' is not convertible to CCOperation.
            kCCAlgorithm3DES,
            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
            key,
            kCCKeySize3DES,
            nil,
            ....
    }
```

Could anybody tell me how to solve this issue? why it works in object-c not swift?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey guys, can you share whole algo that you used for that? I faced a problem with that and cannot find solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459736/ios-3des-with-ecb-return-half-correct-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the arguments to the expected types. For example, `kCCEncrypt` is an `Int`, but the first parameter has the type `CCOperation` which is an alias for `UInt32`.
In contrast to (Objective-)C, Swift does not implicitly convert types:

```
var result = CCCrypt(
    CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
    CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithm3DES),
    CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode),
    key,
    UInt(kCCKeySize3DES),
    ...
```