# iOS 3DES with ECB return half correct data

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, 3des, tripledes

Got a problem with crypting password with 3DES + ECB algo. 
Here is the code I using:

```
class func encryptPassword(pass: String) -> String {

        let keyString        = "123456789012345678901234"
        let keyData: NSData! = (keyString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let keyBytes         = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)

        let data: NSData! = (pass as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let dataLength    = UInt(data.length)
        let dataBytes     = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)

        var cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSize3DES)!
        var cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(cryptData.mutableBytes)
        var cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData.length)

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

        var numBytesEncrypted :UInt = 0

        var cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes, keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes, dataLength,
            cryptPointer, cryptLength,
            &numBytesEncrypted)

        var base64cryptString = ""
        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            let x: UInt = numBytesEncrypted
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            println("cryptLength = \(numBytesEncrypted),\n cryptData = \(cryptData)\n")

            base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

        } else {
            println("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        }

        return base64cryptString
    }

}
```

That works, but failed verifying. I used online-encryptor for that like http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/ 
Select TripleDES and ECB

For code

```
let encrypted = Utils.encryptPassword("123456789")
```

Console shows

```
cryptData = <1dd50935 b702084b d164ce3e 9427c493>
```

Online converter shows

```
1dd50935b702084bf9fbee67c9643874
```

i.e first 8 bytes are correct but the last ones - not. How could be that? What could be wrong with code?

=========== EDIT ============

As @Artjom said - there is should be zeroes values added to complete block.

This code in start adds zero values:

```
        // Trim password
        var password = pass.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

        // Adding null padding
        let count = 8 - countElements(password) % 8
        for i in 1...count {
            password += "\0"
        }
```

Then use "password" var instead incoming "pass" to generate "data"

And also remove Padding for options

```
let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a different padding being used. DES has a block size of 8 byte. So the first block is `12345678` and the second block is `9`. Since DES is a block cipher the plaintext must be padded to the next block size.

The online tool probably uses zero padding or no padding which basically means that the other bytes of the block are set to 0x00. You use in your code on the other hand PKCS#7 padding. Remove the PKCS#7 flag, to see if the output matches.

You will have to do the zero padding yourself if the library doesn't provide it. Fill up the password with `\0` bytes until a multiple of the block size is reached during  encryption and remove those zero bytes during decryption.

It is not recommended to use encryption without padding.

Also, password are not usually encrypted, but rather *hashed* with a random salt and multiple iterations. When your user database gets "lost", you don't want the one who found it, to be able to easily reverse the passwords and log in as any user (the assumption being that the encryption key is also easily "loseable"). Using a strong cryptographic hash function on the other hand has the advantage that it is really infeasible to reverse the hash.

Comment: Thanks for answer, you're definitely right - when I remove PKCS#7 padding  it start to give same answer as online tool, but only if password length is divisible for 8, i.e 8, 16, 24 etc. Otherwise it return error -4303 - kCCAlignmentError

Comment: I see. In this case, you have to manually fill up the plaintext with zero bytes. Please note that passwords shouldn't ever be encrypted. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Artjom. I need to crypt password to send it to server, where backend could crypt existing password and compare results. If iOS side will use random salted hashing - how server could repeat it?

Comment: The salt is not secret. It is used to stop attacks based on rainbow tables. The iterations are used to make brute-force attacks much much harder. Please look into PBKDF2 with a good hash function like SHA-256.

Comment: I think that just SHA-256 would be enough in this case, but problem also is that for some reason server side could not use hashes function, but default WordPress4.1, which, as I understand, uses random values to generate hash. It seems to be problematically to reproduce it on iOS side. Here is a source code https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-phpass.php